# Maven testNg project building success but not running in command prompt

Tags: java, maven, testng

Please help me to run this simple example. I want to open browser through command prompt building success fully but not running in cmd (command line)

```
   public class Hello {
WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void a() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\PoojaPatange\\Downloads\\workfolder\\chromedrive\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://ar-ae.citrusstv.com");
}
}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.13.6</version>

    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J80Tl.png)

Please help me to run this simple example. I want to open browser through command prompt:

Images:

Comment: What is not running, which command You're trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following commands in command line to run Your tests:

**0. run all testclasses inside maven project**

```
  mvn test
```

**1. running single test:**

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName#testCaseName test
```

**2. runningalltests(in class):**

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName test
```

**3. (if using testNg) running via testsuite**

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/java/com/testsuites/testsuitAll.xml test
```

Also add in Your pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Addendum to question in comment:

here is how to call one or multiple classes via testng xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Run">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.your.class.AND_ITS_NAME"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: thank you all are working , awesome  its working, can you please help me by explaining how to run project in jenkins

Comment: if i wangt to select only one calss from multiple class files in testng thyen how can i use this mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/java/com/testsuites/testsuitAll.xml test

Comment: I will write down in answer, will extend it.